# Is it possible to use an UDF in MS WORD document's body?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I know in MS Excel one can write a **custom function in VBA module** and then from the excel spreadsheet call it like: `=myfunction(arg1,arg2,...)`

However in VBA for MS WORD is it possible to do such a direct call without having to have a VBA macro/subroutine around it?

Comment: You want to use a UDF (User Defined Function) directly in Word or in the VBA code for Word? Can you give an example, because I don't see how you can use something like this...

Comment: well simple in excel something like: Declare Function myfunction Lib "c:/test.dll" Alias "myfunction@8" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long   then in an excel cell type =myfunction(2,3) [enter] and there is the result in the cell.

Comment: Hmmm... ok, so it seems you want to calculation directly into a Word document's body using a UDF... I don't know if it's possible, but it seems improbable... Maybe with some event handling, but I'm not sure that you will find an event that fit your need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest Word comes to "functions" is field codes. But these are all pre-defined. Years ago, there were requests to introduce "UDF" but the idea was never followed-up on because they'd be a major security issue (malicious code that could execute automatically).

You can get some "automatic" calculation without code by using form fields, but then the document must be protected as a form. You can also use fields, otherwise and without protecting the document, for calculating but the calculation will not update automatically/transparently unless there's code present.

Beyond that, code is required. You can attach to content controls or ActiveX controls embedded on the document surface.

Comment: I can't understand this answer.  Word supports VBA.  Because of earlier abuse of VBA, it is by default disabled, and intentionally slightly awkward to save the first time, but not impossible.  To enable VBA, got to the not-very-intuitive 'options'.  In a box labeled Main Tabs, check the box next to 'Developer'.  In the document view, you'll find a new tab, Developer.  In that tab, click Visual Basic; a new window will appear.  You can definitely write functions, in some places referred to as User Defined Functions, or UDFs.   They existed BEFORE they were recognized as a security issue.